# Blackberry: selecting multiple items

Tags: listview, blackberry

In blackberry, i am displaying a contact list with its associated phone numbers. Now i have to select multiple contacts. I can select one contact at a time. But is it possible to select multiple items without check boxes? How can we do this? Should i work on single touch event only and on every touch should add elements in an array. or is there any other way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend your list functionality via adding "mark/unmark" action. Upon clicking on a list row the corresponding data block gets marked or unmarked. Use drawListRow() to draw "mark" symbol for every marked line.

And when it is time just collect all marked items from the list for further processing.

Comment: i had the same issue can you please send some sample code for marking and unmarking

Comment: A simple pointer is available here: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Create_list_which_users_can_select_multiple_items_509616_11.jsp